# Scrolling not working on Iphone

Tags: html, scroll

I have the following div and the native scrolling does not work on it.  Is there anything from this code that could possible be caused the scrolling to fail?  Or is there something I can add to this to make the scrolling work?

```
<div id='calvw' style='overflow= hidden;'>    
  <a id='calevvw' dhx_l_id='#id#' data-ajax='false' href='eventview.php?eventid=#id#'
class='dhx_list_item dhx_list_day_events_time'
 style='width:{common.widthSize()}; height:{common.heightSize()};
border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb; padding:{common.padding}px;
 margin:{common.margin}px; overflow:hidden;'>    
</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the div you are tying to have scroll is `#calvw`, this won't work, as you have `overflow:hidden` on it.

Change the css of that element to:

```
overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

To enable native, momentum scrolling.

Comment: this works to scroll but for some reason now when i scroll down as soon as I let go it snaps the whole div back up and I can't click on the things that are below. I can see them but then as soon as I let go they go back up.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try giving the scrollable div a height.